# Intel NUC Ubuntu doesn't wake up BIOS start Time

Tags: boot, shutdown, intel, wakeup, rtc

Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS
NUC7i3DNK Bios Version 0080 (Latest 10/2023)
I want to turn of the device in the evening using cron "shutdown", the device is shutting down successfully.
The BIOS wake time is set to 8am, and the Boot Source "Normal Boot" in the morning but the device is not booting up.
Only the PowerLED is on but the screen is black an the device has startet.
It drives me crazy because sporadically it boots successful but in the most cases not.